# Why does this JavaScript code (module pattern for RequireJS and Node.js) work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, module, requirejs

With my limited understanding of RequireJS and Node.js  (plus JavaScript in general), I usually take a look at the source of some well-known JavaScript libraries. Every time I see something like this:

```js
( // Wrapping
    function (root, factory) {
        if (typeof exports === 'object') { // Node.js

            var underscore = require('underscore');
            var backbone = require('backbone');

            module.exports = factory(underscore, backbone);

        } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { // Require.JS

            define(['underscore', 'backbone'], factory);

        } 
    }(this, function (_, Backbone) { // Factory function, the implementation
        "option strict";

        function Foo() {}

        return Foo; // Export the constructor
    })
); // Wrapping
```

What I can understand (hopefully):

- The anonymous function that wraps the code is automatically executed when the script is uncluded in a `<script>` tag
- This code works with both RequireJS and Node.js (`if` checks in the very beginning); the result of `factory` function is either assigned to `module.exports` (Node.js) or used as argument of `define` function (RequireJS).

**Q1**: how this code works without RequireJS and Node.js? `if` and `else if` checks would fail, `factory` function is never executed and the scripts returns nothig.

**Q2**: what's the purpose of passing `this` as `root` argument? It's never used

Comment: Are you sure that it does work without RequireJS or Node.js?  My limited understanding of JavaScript (and this possibly wrong) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aM3ZT/) makes me think you can't access Foo()

Comment: @nekman Ahh I see it assumes at least Backbone is available.  That's smart

Comment: @JasonSperske not sure at 100%, but look at nekman answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think the code snipped in your question will not work with browser globals. The pattern used in this snipped is called UMD - Universal Module Definition. In fact there are many variations of this pattern, you can browse more examples on https://github.com/umdjs/umd

As for the questions:

**Q1**
This snippet will not work in browsers without RequireJS or any other AMD loader, for obvious reasons - there only two checks - for the NodeJS and define function, so without using AMD library the factory function won't be called.

To make the factory function called just add another condition for browser globals

```
if (typeof exports === 'object') { // Node.js
    var underscore = require('underscore');
    var backbone = require('backbone');
    module.exports = factory(underscore, backbone);

} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) { // Require.JS
     define(['underscore', 'backbone'], factory);
} else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(root._, root.Backbone);
}
```

Note that we used root object passed to the wrapper function and as [nekman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141363/nekman) pointed out it will be set to `window` in browser environment, so we just pass global objects defined on that window to the factory, these objects usually defined by other `script` tags on the page. Hope this answers your second question.

Comment: +1, thanks for the UMD link! As I said I'm learning about JavaScript and what I can't understand is how one can access `Foo` constructor when not using a Node.js or Require.JS. The only way is to write `root.Foo = factory(root._, root.Backbone)`, right?

Comment: Actually I've found the answer to my comment here: https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/returnExports.js

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it, you just return your object (`Foo`) and if  we are in browser we should add it to the `root` (which is window) so that other modules can see it.

Answer (score 2):

**Q1:** If both the `if` and the `else if` fails, the only thing to assume is that `underscore` and `Backbone` is loaded from a `<script>` tag. For a while ago, I [added a commit](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/commit/d4f07c85122eaee3d47b1cdefe74da2b4c42b80a#backbone.localStorage.js) to the [Backbone.localStorage plugin](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) that did the same assumption.

**Q2:** The `this` will point to the "global object" (`window` in a browser environment and `global` in a Node.js environment). In your case, it isn't used and do not need to be passed in. The `factory` alone would be enough.

Comment: For **Q1**: I can't understand the lines that are being executed when the `if` and `else if` fail (i.e. browser). Can you explain that? How can I access `Foo()`?

Comment: Yes, that is correctly spooted! If both fails, then there should be a: `else { factory(_, Backbone); }` to access the factory and `Foo`.

Comment: Even with `return factory(_, Backbone)` I can't figure out how, when including the script with `<script>` tag, one can access `Foo`...